# Ruby on rails trouble with nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a **clan.rb** and **clan_options.rb**

**clan.rb**

```
class Clan < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :options, :class_name => "ClanOptions", :foreign_key => "clan_id", dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :options
end
```

**clan_options.rb**

```
class ClanOptions < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :clan
end
```

To create an edit form for **clan.rb** and **clan_options.rb** I use the following in **edit.html.erb**:

```
<%= form_for @clan, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'} do |clan| %>
    <fieldset>
        <!-- Form stuff -->
        <%= clan.fields_for :options do |o| %>
            <!-- o.text_field -->
        <% end %>
    </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

I can update the fields of **clan.rb** but when I try to edit the value backgroundurl it won't save it. Backgroundurl is one of the **clan_options.rb**

**clans_controller.rb**

```
class ClansController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :check_login, :only => [:new, :edit]
    before_filter :check_bound, :only => [:new, :edit]
    before_filter :check_clan, :only => :new

    def update
        @clan = Clan.find(params[:id])
        if @clan.update_attributes(clan_update_params)
            flash[:status] = TRUE
            flash[:alert] = "Successfully updated your clan."
            redirect_to clan_path(params[:id])
        else
            flash[:status] = FALSE
            flash[:alert] = @clan.errors.full_messages

            redirect_to edit_clan_path(@clan.id)
        end
    end

    def edit
        clan = Clan.where(id: params[:id])
        if !clan.blank?
            @clan = Clan.find(params[:id])

            user = User.where(id: session[:user_id])
            if !user.blank?
                #De gebruiker is ingelogt en zit in de clan
                @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
                if @clan.id != @user.clan.id
                    flash[:status] = FALSE
                    flash[:alert] = 'That was not your clan, you may not edit theirs.'
                    redirect_to clans_path
                elsif @user.clanmember.group.rank != 10
                    flash[:status] = FALSE
                    flash[:alert] = "You must be the leader to edit the clan."
                    redirect_to clan_path(@clan.id)
                end
            end
        else
            flash[:status] = FALSE
            flash[:alert] = 'that clan doesn\'t exist or has been removed.'
            redirect_to clans_path
        end
    end

    def clan_params
        params.require(:clan).permit(:name, :prefix, :description, :user_id)
    end

    def clan_update_params
        params.require(:clan).permit(:name, :prefix, :description, :user_id, options: [:id, :clan_id, :backgroundurl])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it by changing

```
def clan_update_params
    params.require(:clan).permit(:name, :prefix, :description, :user_id, options: [:id, :clan_id, :backgroundurl])
end
```

to

```
def clan_update_params
    params.require(:clan).permit(:name, :prefix, :description, :user_id, options_attributes: [:backgroundurl])
end
```